# Java DOM - NULL pointer exception

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML document using DOM in Java. The data looks like this:

```
<nodes totalCount="48" count="10">
  <node type="A" id="83" label="label1">
    <record>new</record>
    <createTime>12345</createTime>
  </node>
  <node type="A" id="77" label="label2">
    <record>new</record>
    <createTime>4567</createTime>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

This is the relevant portion of my code that I am using to parse:

```
Document doc =  dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(reader));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
Log.w(TAG, "Dom Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("node");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength();temp++) {
        Element element = (Element) nList.item(temp);
        NodeList time = element.getElementsByTagName("createTime");
        Element line = (Element) time.item(0);
        String value =getDataFromElement(line);  
        Log.w(TAG, "Create time: " + value );
 }
```

And my *getDataFromElement* method is

```
public static String getDataFromElement(Element e) {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
          CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
          return cd.getData();
        }
   return "";
}
```

My problem is, it gives `null pointer exception` after printing the first value of createTime at

`getDataFromElement()` method

Can anyone help me diagnose this issue?

Comment: FYI iam using javax.xml.parsers... and org.w3c.dom.... classes.

Comment: if you respected people's time a little more, you would give us a SSCCE and wouldn't have had to explain that.

Comment: which row exactly throws this exception?

Comment: the line Node child = e.getFirstChild() throws it.Also it prints the createTime first time then throws the exception..

Comment: For what its worth, your code compiles and runs for me with no problems.

Comment: Thanks all and I guess i have found the reason i.e after a few node elements there is a nested element with same name node like <node>... <node></node>..</node> but how do i handle this

Comment: for simplicity, just use try/catch and discard any element that returns a null.

Comment: how do i get attribute values of element if exists any, like the label attribute in the current example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try/catch to eliminate unwanted nodes:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat so.xml ElementTest.java; java ElementTest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes totalCount="48" count="10">
<node type="A" id="83" label="label1">
<record>new</record>
<createTime>12345</createTime>
<node type="B">
</node>
</node>
<node type="A" id="77" label="label2">
<record>new</record>
<createTime>4567</createTime>
</node>
</nodes>
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
public class ElementTest {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  InputStream reader = ElementTest.class.getResourceAsStream("so.xml");
  DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(
   ).newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(reader));
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  System.out.println("Dom Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("node");
  for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength();temp++) {
   Element element = (Element) nList.item(temp);
   NodeList time = element.getElementsByTagName("createTime");
   Element line = (Element) time.item(0);
   try {
    String value =getDataFromElement(line);  
    System.out.println("Create time: " + value );
   } catch (Exception problem) {
    System.err.println("problem element " + line + ": " + problem);
   }
  }
 }
 public static String getDataFromElement(Element e) {
  Node child = e.getFirstChild();
  if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
   CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
   return cd.getData();
  }
  else return "";
 }
}
Dom Root element :nodes
Create time: 12345
problem element null: java.lang.NullPointerException
Create time: 4567
```

Comment: Just add another <node> element within a node element it throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Hey thats not in my hands, i receive it as a template from the server and my program has to parse it.

Comment: Thanks for the help jcomeau_ictx, but what if i want to even get that node value as well?

Comment: extract whatever value you want from it, just make sure you trap your exceptions in case it's not what you expect. got to go work out now, good luck.

Comment: Thanks dude.. And congrats for the GOLD!!

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1735/discussion-between-technocrat-and-jcomeau-ictx)

Comment: please edit the question to describe more precisely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when any "node"-element has no "createTime"-element

Comment: well all the node elements have createTime elements within them

Comment: Yup its because another node element is encountered before createTime element in the XML as we go down..